# flex popup not displayed properly

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, popup

In my flex application, there is a popup that behaves randomly. Most of the time the popup works correctly, but sometimes its content doesn't render correctly. Only some labels are shown on a greyish background. Screenshots:

Correct popup:

[image]

Incorrect popup:

[image]

I use the function PopUpManager.createPopUp() to create the popup.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thanks for reading!

Comment: we probably need a bit more information... but it seems less large on the second screenshot. Maybe you reached the minimum size of the component?

Comment: Thanks for replying ZNK-M! I checked again and the sizes seem to be the same. What else do you need to know? BTW, this in fact happened to different popups of different sizes as well.

Comment: In the incorrect case, it looks like some of the styles are not applied. Does that appear to be the only thing missing/wrong?

Comment: in fact it seems the container is completely hidden... but still displays the content... you know a way to repeat the issue or it occurs randomly?

Comment: I don't have any way to reproduce this problem. It occurs randomly, and seems to happen more often when I use remote desktop. I don't think this is a styling problem since the title is totally missing in the incorrect case. This probably has more to do with the creation of the popup's components but I have no way to track it down.  Thanks again!

Comment: Some more information on this: I basically have a menu from which items can be selected to create several tabs in the same application. If there are too many tabs opened at the same time then the popup problem occurs.